# How to get the selected value from a dropdown list within a table in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

In my project I have table showing a list of data. I also have a button in the table to get the details of the selected record, in this case, I only want to get the Id and the selected value from the dropdown that is in the table. So,

I have a controller with two arrays like this this:

```
$scope.selectItem = "";
$scope.ArrayOne = [{Id: 1, Name: "John Doe" },
                    {Id: 2, Name: "Jane Doe" }]

$scope.ArrayTwo = [{Id: 1, Status: "Paid"},
                  {Id: 2, Status: "Unpaid"}]

$scope.getDetails = function(id){
    console.log(id) // getting Id here but I also need to some get the Id of the selected item in the dropdown but I'm not too sure on how to achieve this.
}
```

Then I'm looping the arrays in my view like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in ArrayOne"> 
        <td>{{a.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{a.Name}}</td>
        <!-- looping through array two here --> 
        <td> 
            <select ng-model="selectedItem.Id" ng-options="b.Id as b.Status"></select>
        <td>
        <td><button ng-click="vm.getDetails(a.Id)"> getInfo </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not so sure if how to achieve this, could someone help please? Or how would you go about to achieve this? 
Thank you.

*EDIT:* One other thing i may have forgotten to mention... when i select the dropdown for the first record in the table .. it auto-fills up all the other drop downs in the table . How can i change this to only fill the dropdown for the selected record in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your html to the following,

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in ArrayOne track by $index"> 
        <td>{{a.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{a.Name}}</td>
        <!-- looping through array two here --> 
        <td> 
            <select ng-model="selectedIdArray[$index]" ng-options="b.Id as b.Status for b in ArrayTwo"></select>
        <td>
        <td><button ng-click="getDetails(a.Id, $index)"> getInfo </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the `Id` of the selected item will be populated into `selectedIdArray` scope variable which is an array which you can use in your controller if you know the `$index` value.

```
$scope.ArrayOne = [{Id: 1, Name: "John Doe" },
                {Id: 2, Name: "Jane Doe" }];

$scope.ArrayTwo = [{Id: 1, Status: "Paid"},
              {Id: 2, Status: "Unpaid"}];

// Creating an array of length same as length of ArrayOne. 
// Note that the default value of every element of the array will be "undefined"
$scope.selectIdArray = new Array($scope.ArrayOne.length); 

$scope.getDetails = function(id, index) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log($scope.selectedIdArray[index]); // Id of the selected item
};
```

Make sure to handle the cases when the user clicks the button without selecting anything from dropdown by checking whether `$scope.selectedIdArray[index]` is `undefined` or not in your `getDetails(id, index)` function.

The reason why I've used an array to store the selected value is because the `ng-model` clause is inside `ng-repeat` statement there by making all the dropdowns having the same `ng-model` value if we didn't use an array. I've used `$index` which `ng-repeat` offers to achieve that.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks works well .. please also see my updated question! Thank you

Comment: That's because same variable is binded via `ng-model` for each dropdown. My bad I forgot that `ng-model` is inside `ng-repeat` statement. I've update my answer. Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Wow .. I'm so thankful really am!  i appreciate every sing effort and explanation you've offered .. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In button you pass can whole object and get required details.

### html

```
<button ng-click="vm.getDetails(a,b)"> getInfo </button>
```

### controller

```
$scope.getDetails = function(user,payment)
{
    console.log(user.Name+" has "+payment.Status)
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. can you please have a look at my updated question ? thank you .